# How can I select data from last 13 months?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have two tables with exactly same structure

```
table 1 - Data_2020 --> This is an static table which has data from year 2020 and is not being updated anymore (archive table). It has around 4 million records
table 2 - Data_2021 --> This is my current table which is increasing everyday. It has currently 0.8 million records but it will increase till December.
```

Now I need to 'union all' these two tables and I want only last 13 month data every time I run below query

```
Select * from Data_2020 
union all
select * from Data_2021
```

I have to run this every month and need only last 13 month data. How can I apply the filter? I have a date column 'date' in both the tables.

Comment: Saving the same kind of data from different years in different tables might not be the best design choice (for queries like this one). Have you considered something like `select * from ( <current union query goes here> ) where date >= dateadd(month, -13, getdate());` ?

Comment: Why different tables, just store it all in one table. In 20 years you will have 20 tables??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @StartDate datetime,@CurrentDate datetime
set @CurrentDate = GETDATE();
set @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH,-13,@CurrentDate)


SELECT *
FROM Data_2020
WHERE DateFieldName > @StartDate -- Or DateFieldName BETWEEN @StartDate AND @CurrentDate
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Data_2021
WHERE DateFieldName > @StartDate -- Or DateFieldName BETWEEN @StartDate AND @CurrentDate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consider the date column from the tables to get the current max date, you can use this query

```
DECLARE @CurrentMaxDate DATE
SET @CurrentMaxDate = (SELECT Top 1 [Date] FROM Data_2021 ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
;WITH TempCTE AS (
SELECT * FROM Data_2020 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Data_2021
)
SELECT * FROM TempCTE
WHERE [Date] > DATEADD(Month,-13, @CurrentMaxDate)
```

Comment: Thanks the solution worked for me... Earlier when i was using the direct filter [Date] > DATEADD(Month,-13, getdate()) thr query was running for more than 15 minutes and did not complete, but this worked in 40 seconds....

Comment: I am sorry, i tried that but my reputation is low..